# How to change an attribute value depend on the device used to view the page

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm doing a page that represents cards of restaurants one of the cards components is rating stars to show the restaurant rating, the rating stars are imported from the react-rating-stars-component package, I want to change the size attribute of it if the user visits on a mobile device

the rating code at the rating component is

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactStars from 'react-rating-stars-component'; 

    function ReadStars (props) {
    return (
        <ReactStars 
            value={props.value}
            count={5}
            size={30}
            edit={false}
            isHalf={true}
        /> 
    )
```

here is the code card component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Avatar from "./Avatar";
import Detail from "./Detail";
import ReadStars from "./Star-rating";
import Favorite from "./Favorite";


function Card(props) {
  return (
    <div className="cards">
      <Avatar img={props.img} />
      <div className="flexCal">
        <div className="flexRow">
          <div className="flexname">
            <h2 className="name">{props.placeName}</h2>
            <div className="ratingPadd">
              <ReadStars className="rating" value={props.stars}></ReadStars>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="flexfav">
            <h3 className="status">{props.status}</h3>
            <Favorite placeId={props.theCardId} placeName={props.placeName} className="favorite"></Favorite>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flexTypes">
          <h4 className="Type3"> <span>{props.partition}</span> | <span>{props.music}</span> | <span>{props.wifi}</span></h4>
          <Detail detailInfo={props.descreption} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Card;
    }
        export default ReadStars;
```

and here I already set the css ready for it

```
 /* For mobile users  */
/* @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .cards {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
}

.cards img {
  width: 100px;
}
.name{
  max-width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.ratingPadd{
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.flexfav{
  width: 17px;
}
.status{
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.favorite{
  font-size: 20px;
}
.flexTypes{
  gap: 2px;
}
.Type3{
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.info{
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 150px;
}
} */
```

======================================================
UPDATE:
this how I solve the problem it could not be the best solution but work fine with me(using window.innerWidth)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactStars from 'react-rating-stars-component'; 
    function ReadStars (props) {
        // To check the screen width and make the star size fit for it 
        let size1;
        if(window.innerWidth >= 701 && window.innerWidth <= 1050){
            size1=25;
        }else{
            if(window.innerWidth <= 700){
                size1=15;
            }else{
                size1=30;
            }
        }
        console.log(size1);
    return (
        // all these attributes are set by the author of the package
        <ReactStars 
            value={props.value}
            count={5}
            size={size1}
            edit={false}
            isHalf={true}
            activeColor="#ffea00"
        /> 
    )
}
    export default ReadStars;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you need to know there're two approaches on this, one is Javascript, and one is CSS, and you can pick one of the approach.

#### Javascript

```
        <ReactStars 
            value={props.value}
            size={mobileSize}
```

How to find the right `mobileSize`. Please read https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/ to figure out how to get a Javascript parameter and then based on that your `mobileSize`.

#### Css

insert your css to `index.js` or any way to put it into effect

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .star {
    width: 33px
  }
}
```

these media line has to work if your css is properly injected to the site.